# Subtract the size of two arrays

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following structure:

```
[
  {
    name: "A",
    upvotes: [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    downvotes: [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    upvotes: [
      "a"
    ],
    downvotes: [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to retrierbe the most voted object. The most voted object is the one with the greatest `(size(upvotes) - size(downvotes))` value.

For example, here it's A `( 2 - 3 = -1)`.

How can I do this using mongodb aggregation?

Thank's in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Query adds one field with the difference, and then sort by it descending, remove that field, and take the top result(the document with the biggest value on difference)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4CKUjzoKnC8)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "diff": {
        "$subtract": [
          {
            "$size": "$upvotes"
          },
          {
            "$size": "$downvotes"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "diff": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "diff"
    ]
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```